# ¿Por que tengo tantos errores en blazor?

Tags: html, c#, asp.net, razor, blazor

necesito ayuda con una aplicación creada en blazor.
El problemas es que nada mas crearlo sin hacer nada tiene 100 errores sin yo haber empezado a editar nada[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Este sería mi problema no se que puede faltar por que funcionar funciona

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: probaste darle clean solution(limpiar la solucion)? o un dotnet restore en la ubicacion del proyecto en la consola?

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo valides lo siguiente, ya que veo errores de ambigüedad desde el proyecto Client en Blazor.

1. Verifica en program.cs los using y comprueba cuales faltan referencias o cuales están agregado y que causen ambigüedad en tu código.
2. Validar en _imports.razor las librerías utilizadas
3. Verifica la actualización de tus paquetes Nugets (Si piden actualizar, realiza el update)
4. Abre el Console Terminal Nuget y ejecuta el siguiente comando **dotnet restore**
5. Limpia la solución
6. Regenera la solución

Espero haber podido ayudar.